# Sublime 3 Not Building?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

Long story short, I'm running into an issue where Sublime 3 will not build. When I write something like

```
print 'hello world'
```

and then hit build/cmd + b, all I see is `[Finished in 0.1s]`.

I have tried the same in JavaScript, but still, I get the same response.

It was working fine up until this morning, all that I can think that changed was updating OSX. Am I going crazy?

Answer (score 1):

Try to force **Sublime** to use the appropriate build system. (In you case Python). Tools > Build System > Python.